# How to write a regular expression over $\{a,b\}$ such that there're at least $3$ occurrences of adjacent different letters?

Tags: proof-verification, formal-languages, regular-expressions

> How to write a regular expression over $\sum=\{a,b\}$ such that there're at least $3$ occurrences of adjacent different letters? For example, $abab$ is a word in the language as is $babbbaaaaaba$.

I though of the following regular expression:
$$
\sum^*(abab)^*(baba)^*\sum^*(ba+ab)\sum^*(ba+ab)\sum^*(ba+ab)\sum^*
$$

The $(ba+ab)$ will result in either $ba$ or $ab$ in the resulting word. We need exactly three such combinations and anything can be in between of them.

Comment: I don't understand the definition of your language: why is $abab$ in it?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma because $ab$ are two different adjacent letters as well as $ba$. It's just that $ab$, $ba$ and $ab$ overlap in the word.

Comment: Then $abab$ is not covered by your expression...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I actually realized that after your question and then added it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about
$$aa^*bb^*aa^*b(a+b)^*+bb^*aa^*bb^*a(a+b)^*?$$

Comment: Do you think this one is good as well: $(a^+b^+a^+b^++b^+a^+b^+a^+)\sum^*$?